# Removing items from a cart

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I'm working on a webshop in vuex,nodeJS and express and I made a cart.

This is my backend code for removing items from the cart

```
app.delete('/cart/delete', (req, res) => {
const productId = req.body.id;

fs.readFile(CART_DATA_FILE, (err, data) => {
const newCartProducts = JSON.parse(data).map((cartProduct) => {
      if (productId === cartProduct.id && cartProduct.quantity > 1) {
        cartProduct.quantity--;
        if(productId === cartProduct.id  && cartProduct.quantity === 1) {
          cartIndexToRemove = newCartProducts.findIndex(cartProduct => cartProduct.id === 
          productId);
          newCartProducts.splice(cartIndexToRemove, 1);
        }
      }
      return cartProduct;
}).filter((cartProduct) => cartProduct.quantity <= 1);

fs.writeFile(CART_DATA_FILE, JSON.stringify(newCartProducts, null, 4), () => {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.json(newCartProducts);
});
});
});
```

When quantity is 1 I can't remove item from the cart but when quantity is above 1 then it doesn't decreases quantity, it just deletes it all together.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems an asynchronous problem. You might want to create a promise and then return the result in order to write on the file. If you post the file as how it is will be easier to help you out.

Comment: @FernandoPalma [link](https://github.com/markec15/KODIUS/blob/main/server.js) here is the full file.